# Customize Google Map API V3 Marker label

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

```js
function initMap() {
  var uluru = {lat: 13.676442, lng: 100.638276};
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 17,
    center: uluru
  });
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: uluru,
    map: map,
    label: {
      text: "$300k",
      color: "#4682B4",
      fontSize: "30px",
      fontWeight: "bold"
    },
    title: "Hello World!",
    visible: true
  });
}
```

I want to customize the label. I try to find the answers in google documentation they have only few properties to change (https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference#MarkerOptions) then I search on google the most answer is MarkerWithLabel but the problem is the link doesn't work any more http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/tags/markerwithlabel/1.1.9/src/markerwithlabel.js" so I cannot use the library. I attach pictures from my code and what I want. Can any one help me please?

[image: This is the result from my code]

[image: This is what I want]

Answer (score 9):

You can add your own class with `label.className` key:

```
map: map,
draggable: true,

label: {
        
    text: value.title,
    className: 'marker-label',
      
}
```

But you must know that Google adds another styles for every marker programmaticaly:

```
color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
font-size: 14px;
font-family: Roboto, Arial, sans-serif;
```

So you must override its values by yourself programmaticaly not in css according @vikashvishwakarma answer because styles have more priority as classes.

Comment: Thanks! I have used `!important` rule to force the class specific properties, and then removed the default icons by specifying an arbitrary icon to the marker. Finally, I have added a `::before` element to make a css pointer to point the exact location.

Comment: Great, glad it was helped! And yes, sure, you can use `!important` if you want to override its styles exactly in CSS.

Answer (score 6):

The Google Code was deprecated a long time ago. All Google Maps API projects that were hosted on Google Code migrated to Github.

You can find Marker with labels utility library and other utility libraries as well at:

https://github.com/googlemaps/v3-utility-library

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 3):

You can extend `google.maps.OverlayView` class to display custom types of overlay objects on the map. See [working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/andriika/pdc2b85j)

Also, see [official example](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/overlay-popup#maps_overlay_popup-css) and [OverlayView API reference](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/overlay-view)

Answer (score 1):

SO You can customised object by defining in html string then assign to object

```
       let arrayElem = '<h4> Details</h4><br>Employee 
       ID:'+element.EmpID+'<br>Coordinates:'+element.lat+', 
       '+element.lng+'<br>Sequence ID:'+element.seqId+'<br> 
        <a>RouteID</a>:'+RouteId;


        let marker = {icon:'./assets/desticontest.png',
                      label:{text:element.seqId.toString(),
                             fontSize: "20px",
                              fontWeight: "bold",
                              color:'black'},
                      opacity:0.8,
                      infoWindow:arrayElem
                      };
```

Answer (score -1):

How the Google map is rendered here might help you:
http://simplify.quedank.com/loop-google-maps-markers-and-coordinates-from-wordpress-posts/

The idea is that, it's better to separate your marker variable from your initMap(). That way you can create a separate function for your marker then use an addListener to automatically show the label:

```
<!-- Create variable "map" -->
var map;
<!-- Initiate/render map with this function -->
function initMap() {
    <!-- Edit latitude and longitude coordinates to focus on a specific region on the map -->
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        center: { lat: 35.7932977, lng: -78.6551929 },
        scrollwheel: false,
        zoom: 11
    });         
}
<!-- This is the function to add markers for each post. This includes the marker, the information window, and a function to show info when clicked -->
function addMarker(props) {
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: props.coords,
      map: map
    });
    var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
        content: props.content
    });
    marker.addListener('load', function() {
        infoWindow.open(map, marker);
    });
}
```

Then use the 'content' property to add the label as seen on line 52. Something like:

```
addMarker({coords:{lat: 00000000000, lng: 00000000000}, content:'<h5>$2.3M</h5>'});
```