# Customising a Google Maps API V3 Marker label

Tags: google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I am really struggling to customize the label on my map markers. Before anyone comments, I have already tried [Customize Google Map API V3 Marker label](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42323569/customize-google-map-api-v3-marker-label) and that doesn't help. Like everything else I have found, it specifies the marker like this:

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: uluru,
    map: map,
    label: {
      text: "$300k",
      color: "#4682B4",
      fontSize: "30px",
      fontWeight: "bold"
    },
    title: "Hello World!",
    visible: true
  });
```

My code creates the label with marker.setLabel like this:

```
var markersNear = oms.markersNearMarker(marker, false);
if (markersNear.length > 0) {
    marker.setLabel("" + (markersNear.length + 1));
}
marker.setOptions({
    zIndex: markersNear.length
});
```

Unless I've missed something obvious, I'm not able to style the label in the setOptions. Surely there must be a way of doing this.

https://jsfiddle.net/groxmzej/

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates your issue.  Does calling `.setLabel` with an object as in the first example not work for you?

Comment: I've added a jsfiddle as suggested by geocodezip.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You example looks to be working as expected. How are you trying to style it?

`.setLabel(param)` accepts either a string (as in your example) or a [MarkerLabel object](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/marker#MarkerLabel).

```
var customLabel = {
    text: `${markersNear.length + 1}`,
    color: "#4682B4",
    fontSize: "30px",
    fontWeight: "bold"
}
marker.setLabel(customLabel);
```

You can see this implemented in your example with [this jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7j24xtan/).

Comment: Thank you mathewspete. That so very nearly worked. In fact it did work when clicking on a marker for the first time , but  having spiderfied it and unspiderfied again, the label reverted to default styling. I solved that by applying the same styling to oms.addListener('unspiderfy). I've done this jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/5epxjmth/ which shows my final code. I opted to insert a className and specify the styling in CSS rather than directly in the javascript.