# Adding text on a Google Maps

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I just want to add some text on top of a Google Maps.

All I can find is a question from 8 years ago with no answers [How to add a text on google map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25496125/how-to-add-a-text-on-google-map) and another question from 12 years ago that refer to libraries that died half a decade ago. [Is it possible to write custom text on Google Maps API v3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3953922/is-it-possible-to-write-custom-text-on-google-maps-api-v3)

So is there a simple way to add text at a longitude/latitude location on a map (On google maps js api)?

Comment: Can't you just use [infoWindows](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/infowindows)?

Comment: Nah I just want to write a text straight on the map.

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42323569/customize-google-map-api-v3-marker-label

Answer (score 1):

Answer came to me with the morning.

You may not easily be able to just throw text on top of a google maps, but you CAN put an image!

So make an SVG and throw the text you want in it. Then load that SVG as an image on your map.

```js
var markerLabelSVG = '<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><text x="0" y="12" class="svgpathpin" style="font-family:Arial; opacity:.5; font-weight:700">1</text></svg>';
marker_label=new google.maps.Marker({
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(-22,-25),
    map: map,
    title: '',
    icon: { url: 'data:image/svg+xml;charset=UTF-8;base64,' + btoa(markerLabelSVG), scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(20, 20) },
    optimized: false
});
```